# ValidationGroup in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

I have this much

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSaveContest" runat="server" Text="Save &amp; Publish Contest" OnClientClick="javascript:changeInputTexts(); return disableAfterClick();"
                            ValidationGroup="ContestAdd" OnClick="btnSaveContest_Click" />
```

Now I want to call `disableAfterClick()` after all validations are completed. It should be in Client Side. So that I can ensure that the user can click the button only one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function ValidateCreateContest() {
    Page_ClientValidate();
    if (Page_IsValid) {

        $('#<%=btnSaveContest.ClientID%>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        return true;
    }
    else {            
        return false;
    }      

}`
```